# Can this attribute be controlled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, vb.net

Is it possible to control the height/number of items shown in a select dropdown box? Or do I need to code a custom widget? Is this possible?

Forgot to mention I'm using the following code:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" Width="288px" CssClass="Select"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Do you mean the number of items displayed at a time?

Comment: Short answer is yes http://comp345.awardspace.com/select_element_cheatsheet.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the *visible* number of items using the `size` attribute:

```
<select size="3">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option> 
</select>
```

but the number of items in the DropDown itself depends on how many you put there!

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the size attribute automatically change the SELECT from a drop down to a list box?

In 'drop down' mode I believe the size (number of options) of a SELECT is set by browser default.  Each browser has a maximum number of options it will display before adding a vertical scroll bar. In Chrome and Firefox it's 20.  In IE, 30.